# Is there a bookmarklet or extension that allows you to save where you left off in a website (save scroll position)

Tags: webapp-rec

What I'm looking for is a a bookmarklet, extension or web app that allows you to save your location when reading long articles, tutorials, e-books and other long web content.

For example, reading something like the Rails tutorial, I keep forgetting where I left off, and I would like to have some sort of solution that behaves like Kindle and remembers my last location in it. It can be a bookmarklet (that saves in a cookie), an extension or a web app (e.g. I wish Pocket had this feature).

However, I've searched for a few hours, and all I could find is this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remember-my-comics/pcahmjijfdogbhpeengjbpgaomcbfekd

Answer (score -1):

Try [Readability](http://www.readability.com/) - not only will it save the location, it also synchronizes across several devices, and, my favorite, predicts how long will it tale you to finish reading the article (in minutes).

**Update 2016:** As of September 30, 2016 [Readability is discontinued](https://medium.com/@readability/the-readability-bookmarking-service-will-shut-down-on-september-30-2016-1641cc18e02b#.6mntzzl6z). They recommend switching to [Mercury Reader](https://mercury.postlight.com/) - although I've never tried it, and therefore cannot recommend it.

Comment: Great, I've heard of them but never got the time to give it a test, will do now, thanks!

Comment: Tested it, and it works great, I wonder though if there is anything that keeps the code highlighting and formatting as is, well, you can get it all :)

Comment: Unfortunately, Readability is now discontinued.

Answer (score -1):

for firefox there is [advanced bookmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/advanced-bookmaks-add-on/) this stores scroll position and the position of selected texts. For chrome there is ["neater bookmarks"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/neater-bookmarks/ofgjggbjanlhbgaemjbkiegeebmccifi) this stores the scroll position.